# Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component for Selenium-webdriver 2.35.0 and Firefox 23.0.1 combination

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For automating one of the tests, I've to perform drag and drop. Hence, I tried to achieve it following way:

```
driver.action.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform
```

but it results into an error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.
```

I ran this test on following configuration:

1. Firefox 23.0.1
2. Selenium WebDriver 2.35.0

I chose above combinations because [change log](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES) says - with Selenium WebDriver 2.35.0 and Firefox 23, native event components works fine.

Even though I used correct Firefox and Selenium WebDriver versions, it's throwing error.

Looking at stackoverflow, I can see same kind of issue has been asked several times. And answers to these questions are like: `either downgrade/upgrade Firefox, Selenium WebDriver versions`

Everytime Firefox or Selenium WebDriver version is upgraded, users face these problems. Hence user look at change log and try find right combination of Firefox and WebDriver. (and even though I followed it, I'm facing problem)

My questions are:

1. Is there easiest way which will help to choose correct Firefox and Selenium WebDriver versions?
2. Or is there any workaround for mouse interactions using Selenium?

so that we can get rid of `Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.`error.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have the option of "manually" executing the JS function which is triggered by the drag and drop, using driver.execute_script("JavaScript code here").

Comment: Yes, javascript helps when things aren't achieved with Selenium API. That could be workaround. But could you please provide code for `"JavaScript code here"` part for `driver.execute_script("JavaScript code here")`?